# Rspec testing method that modifies instance variable

Tags: rspec

How do I test that an instance method is properly modifying an instance variable?

Given the class:

```
class MyClass
  attr_reader :ary
  def initialize
    @ary = []
  end
  def update (value)
    @ary << value
  end
end
```

How would I test that #update is correctly modifying @ary?
So far I have:

```
describe MyClass do
  before { @my_class = MyClass.new }
  describe '#update' do
    it 'should correctly update the value' do
       expect(@my_class.update('some_value')).to #what comes next?
```

The matcher is looking to evaluate the return value of #update, not the value of @ary, which is what I want.

Comment: Should I insert a `before {@my_class.update('some_value'}` after `describe '#update' do`, then use `expect(@my_class.ary).to eq(['some_value'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a concise example

```
describe MyClass do
  describe "#update" do
    it "appends the argument to the array" do
       subject.update(value = 'some_value')
       expect(subject.ary).to eq([value])
    end
  end
end
```

A few notes compared to your initial code. First of all, you can rely on `subject`. `subject` is defined as

```
described_class.new
```

It's like having

```
describe MyClass do
  subject { described_class.new }

  describe "#update" do
    ...
  end
end
```

or

```
describe MyClass do
  describe "#update" do
    subject = described_class.new
  end
end
```

which essentially means

```
describe MyClass do
  describe "#update" do
    subject = MyClass.new
  end
end
```

If you just want to test an instance, use `subject`. Do not use before actions to set instance variables.

The following line

```
subject.update(value = 'some_value')
expect(subject.ary).to eq([value])
```

is essentially a shortcut for

```
value = 'some_value'
subject.update(value)
expect(subject.ary).to eq([value])
```

It helps me to not write the expected string twice. The rest should be quite easy to understand.

You may also want to test the return value, if this is relevant.

```
describe MyClass do
  describe "#update" do
    it "appends the argument to the array" do
      subject.update(value = 'some_value')
      expect(subject.ary).to eq([value])
    end

    it "returns the item that was added" do
      value = 'some_value'
      expect(subject.update(value)).to eq(value)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Is there some kind of consensus on when to use `subject`? I have seen numerous references to [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-not) that says to avoid `subject` for simpler tests.

Comment: For very simple tests, I generally rely on `subject`, whereas for more complex specs I tend to use explicit subjects to make sure the code is more readable. Actually, I personally prefer to always have an explicit subject either in the spec block or as `subject {}` statement. But this is a personal preference.

Comment: Agree with always using explicit class name instead of described_class.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method first, then check for `@ary`

```
describe MyClass do
  before { @my_class = MyClass.new }
    describe '#update' do
      it 'should correctly update the value' do
        @my_class.update('some_value')
        expect(@my_class.ary).to equal(['some_value'])
```